# Comparison of columns from two files and create new column

Tags: join, awk

I want to compare first two columns from `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, if match found add new columns (3rd and 4th) to `file1.txt` with values found from column 3 and 4 of `file2.txt` and "NA" to non-match.

#### file1.txt

```
ch1  100
ch1  200
ch3  100
ch4  200
```

#### file2.txt

```
ch1  100  0.5  0.6
ch1  200  0.1  1.2
ch3  400  0.2  0.9
ch4  200  1.0  3.0
```

#### outputfile.txt

```
ch1  100  0.5  0.6
ch1  200  0.1  1.2
ch3  100  NA   NA
ch4  200  1.0  3.0
```

I tried join/awk commands but it is not giving the desired output.

Comment: Which `join` and `awk` commands did you try?  What was wrong with the result?

Comment: I tried left-join @Jonathan.

Comment: I meant — please show us in the question the best attempt you feel you made and the result you got.  At the moment, we can't tell anything about what you know about either `join` or `awk`.  Either can probably be made to work, but the techniques are different.  For example, how many join columns can you specify with `join`?  What does that imply for your problem?  Do you know the `FNR==NR` condition in `awk`?

Comment: join -a1 -1 1 -2 1 -e "NA" -o 0,1.1,2.2,2.3     <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file1.txt | sort)     <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file2.txt | sort) |  sed 's/_/ /' |  column  -t |  sort

Comment: Got it done. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Can you post the code to solve with the awk command. I am getting (segmentation fault core dumped) error when using the join command with my large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `awk` technique reads the whole of `file1.txt` into memory.  If your files are too big to fit, then considerably more effort is required (but it can be done even so).

```
awk 'FNR == NR { k[$1,$2] = 1; next }
     { if (k[$1,$2] == 1) { print $0; k[$1,$2] = 2 } }
     END { for (i in k) { if (k[i] == 1) { sub(SUBSEP, " ", i); print i, "NA", "NA" } } }' \
    file1.txt file2.txt
```

The first line reads the first file and records the keys that are read.  The second line does most of the processing.  If the key of $1, $2 in the second file matches a record, then print `$0`, and record that the key was matched (by setting the value to 2 from 1).  The third line (the END block) looks at all the keys in `k` and if the value is not 2, it was not matched so the key is printed with the two NA columns.  The `sub(SUBSEP, " ", i)` part fixes the sub-separator between the two keys in `i` into a space.

Raw output from the `awk`:

```
ch1  100  0.5  0.6
ch1  200  0.1  1.2
ch4  200  1.0  3.0
ch3 100 NA NA
```

After passing through `column -t` (on my Mac):

```
ch1  100  0.5  0.6
ch1  200  0.1  1.2
ch4  200  1.0  3.0
ch3  100  NA   NA
```

Comment: thank you. It works but gives the output unsorted and when I try to sort it with "sort" command, it is still running with more than 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Do you have any insights how to overcome these issues? "join" is also not able to work on my large data.

Comment: How big are your files — number of lines, number of characters?  How many of the rows in `file1.txt` aren't matched in `file2.txt`?  How are you doing the sort (what is the `sort` command you're using)?  Are you doing that before or after the `column -t`?  What size machine have you got (RAM, CPU speed)?  How much spare disk space do you have?  How long does it take to sort `file2.txt` on its own?

Comment: These are the file sizes: file1.txt is of size 680 MB with 28 million lines (3 columns tab-delimited).

file2.txt is of size 470 MB with 13 million lines (5 columns tab-delimited). I am working remotely on a server with 128GB RAM. I tried to sort with the command "sort -k1,1 -k2,2n in.txt > out.txt"

Comment: Those are non-negligible file sizes.  However, they should all fit in memory, so it probably isn't a memory problem.  You're going to have some 15M rows tagged with "NA" attributes unless there's a lot of repetition in `file1.txt` on the key fields.  24 characters per line in `file1.txt`; 36 in `file2.txt`.  Still, the output should be less than 1 GiB.  Note that you can have `sort` overwrite one of its input files safely with `sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -o in.txt in.txt`, for example.

Comment: On my Mac, I generated random data and sorting 28,000 rows of 24 bytes took 0.3 s; 280,000 took 4.0 s; 2,800,000 took about 50 s; and 28,000,000 took about 600s (with the random data generation taking about 65s and the sort over 500s).  My machine's got 16 GiB RAM, and a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 from 2011.  Your output is probably a bit bigger than that, though it isn't clear by how much.  I suspect that that seeing 10-15 minutes for sorting the data is not all that unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

```
join -a1 -1 1 -2 1 -e "NA" -o 1.1,2.2,2.3 \
    <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file1.txt | sort)  <(sed 's/ \+/_/' file2.txt | sort) |
sed 's/_/ /' | column -t
```